# Using GWT with Mac OS X Leopard

Tags: macos, gwt, osx-leopard

I'm just starting out with GWT but I can't even run the getting started example without getting the following error:

> Invalid memory access of location 0x10 eip=0x93624148

I am aware of the "java hosted mode 32 bit" stuff, anyway I tried every combination I could think of and still could not get away with that error.
I tried:

- Using the eclipse plugin
- Setting all possible jvm switches in eclipse to 1.5
- Use the command line tool
- Set the java environment to java 5 32 bit in the preference pane, and do all of the previous options again, without success (I checked that effectively "java -version" gives me the right 32 bit jvm)

Any suggestion? I can't believe that something which should be apparently immediate is so difficult ...

Thanks for your help

Best regards

Nicola Montecchio

Comment: What version of GWT SDK are you using?

Comment: gwt 2 seems to work, after installing the plugin on Safari thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be fixed in GWT 2.0.

Alternatively, try using the WebKit Nightly.

Steps here:

http://grack.com/blog/2009/11/16/fix-for-gwt-hosted-mode-crash-with-safari-4-0-4/

Answer (score 1):

See [release](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/releases/release-notes-1.7.1.html#Release_Notes_Current) notes for latest SDK 1.7.1.

You might need to switch to Snow Leopard to get it working.

*Update:* GWT 2.0 is just out today. Give it a go, even thought I've not seen anything related to Leopard in the change list.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Maybe I'll try with previous versions of GWT until I switch. At the moment I'm using the latest GWT (1.7.1), eclipse 3.5 and Leopard 10.5.8
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used gwt a lot on my mac with OS X 10.5 on. It actually worked fine. Have you also set the java class version in the projects facets menu in the project preferences to java 5?

You can also provide which java to use in the launch configuration, you don't need to modify in the Mac OSX preference pane.

I actually upgraded to 10.6 when it came out, and it made life with GW easier.

Hope it helped, if you have any more questions let me know.

Best - István